# How can I inject a service into an Entity Framework AddDbContextFactory lambda function in Blazor Server?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dependency-injection, blazor

In Blazor server, how can I inject a **scoped** service into the lambda below so that I can read the authenticated user and select a SQL connection string based on the user.

```
builder.Services.AddDbContextFactory<GlueDbContext>((provider, options) =>
    {
        var AuthenticationStateProvider = provider.GetService<AuthenticationStateProvider>();
        // *** Compiles but FAILS because AuthenticationStateProvider is not a Singleton ***
        var user = _authenticationStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync().Result.User;
        //
        string sqlConnectString = SomeFunctionDerivingTheConnectionFromTheUser(user);
        options.UseMySql(connectionString);
    });
```

Comment: [This resource](https://samwalpole.com/using-scoped-services-inside-singletons) should be helpful.

Comment: u wouldn't do it in the registration of the DbContext, but rather in the logic where the DBcontext is injected.

Comment: where you can calling the thing which needs db access... that is at the point where you could decide the dbcontext, aka if person A then inject dbA if person B inject dbB, but even if you work out a better way, you still wouldnt be injecting into the registration.

Comment: https://www.thereformedprogrammer.net/building-asp-net-core-and-ef-core-multi-tenant-apps-part1-the-database/

https://medium.com/swlh/entity-framework-core-multitenancy-112d82cd89c6

Answer (score 0):

Following [this](https://samwalpole.com/using-scoped-services-inside-singletons) link, it should look something like this (I'm typing without IDE so it may contain some typos):

```cs
var serviceScopeFactory = provider.GetService<IServiceScopeFactory>(); //IServiceScopeFactory is a singleton, so you can easily get it here
using var scope = serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope();
var authenticationStateProvider = scope.GetService<AuthenticationStateProvider>();
//...
```

Comment: how does this answer "How can I inject a scoped service into the Lambda below so that I can read the Authenticated User and select a SQL connection string based on the user."

Comment: @Seabizkit, you get `authenticationStateProvider`, which is a scoped service, and you can use it inside of the lambda function.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#blazor-server-authentication

my understanding is you would not have access to this during registration

Comment: @Seabizkit I think your reasoning is correct, after all the server cannot know the user before establishing the connection. In that case, I suppose the check for which connection to use cannot happen before receiving a request from the client. That means that the question "which connection string to use" must be answered per scope. Nevertheless, my answer answers the first part of the question "how to inject a scoped service into lambda below...".

Comment: The Lamdba only gets called once the App has started running and set its AuthenticationState.  I was missing a (defaulted) parameter that needed setting to ServiceLifetime.Scoped.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that.  Services.Add.... simply adds classes/interfaces to a collection.  It's not till later that the services container gets initialised, and until you use a DI object that an instance of that object gets initialised.

To illustrate the process, here's the code to set up a services container `serviceProvider` in a test.

```
        var services = new ServiceCollection();
        services.AddDbContextFactory<InMemoryWeatherDbContext>(options => options.UseInMemoryDatabase("WeatherDatabase"));
        services.AddSingleton<IDataBroker, ServerDataBroker>();
        var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
```

Whatever you design, it needs rethinking.  You can't get a user until an SPA session has initialized.

Comment: "Whatever you design, it needs rethinking. You can't get a user until an SPA session has initialized" agreed this is the answer

Answer (score 0):

AddDbContextFactory has a defaulted parameter set to Singleton.
add **ServiceLifetime.Scoped**

```
builder.Services.AddDbContextFactory<GlueDbContext>((provider, options) =>
    {
        var AuthenticationStateProvider = provider.GetService<AuthenticationStateProvider>();
        var user = _authenticationStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync().Result.User;
        string sqlConnectString = SomeFunctionDerivingTheConnectionFromTheUser(user);
        options.UseMySql(connectionString);
    }, ServiceLifetime.Scoped);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).